# three.js shape holes height

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to build a Mesh with holes from an original Shape and then an ExtrudedGeometry. The problem is that the holes I add always go trough the whole height of the resulting Mesh. Is there any way to make the holes shorter in height, so in the end these don't go across the whole shape?

Reference code for the shape to extruded:

```
var heartShape = new THREE.Shape();

heartShape.moveTo( 25, 25 );
heartShape.bezierCurveTo( 25, 25, 20, 0, 0, 0 );
blah

var innerCircle = new THREE.Path();
innerCircle.moveTo(blah);
heartShape.holes.push(innerCircle);

var extrudeSettings = { amount: 8, bevelEnabled: true, bevelSegments: 2, steps: 2, bevelSize: 1, bevelThickness: 1 };

var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( heartShape, extrudeSettings );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial() );
```

Thanks!

Comment: To achieve the thing you want, it's better to use "Constructive Solid Geometry" (CSG). You can start from [here](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/12/10/constructive-solid-geometry-with-csg-js/), [here](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/CSG.html) and read [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32778617/three-js-why-is-csg-js-not-working) about new syntax. The lib itself is [here](https://github.com/chandlerprall/ThreeCSG)

Comment: @prisoner849 Yeah, CSG definitely helps reasoning about this sort of things, but the problem is that it is too expensive to use everywhere (I'm already using it). So, I'm exploring simple enough but less expensive approaches.

Answer (score 1):

There is no separate argument for hole depth in THREE.ExtrudeGeometry. You will need two separate operations to solve it.

One solution could be to "plug" it with another extrude based on your inner circle path (convert to Shape first).

```
var extrudeSettingsForPlug = { amount: 4, bevelEnabled: true, bevelSegments: 2, steps: 2, bevelSize: 1, bevelThickness: 1 }; 

var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( innerCircleShape, extrudeSettingsForPlug );
```